# How can I get app icon from app id in steam?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I want to get app icon for steam app using app id. The one what you see in steam library or this page: `https://store.steampowered.com/news` or https://steamcommunity.com/home

For example: steam id is `730` and I want to get this `https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg` or this `https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg` url. Not sure where you get `69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4` part from and what does it mean. Maybe there API endpoint to get this url?

I tried using this endpoint: `https://store.steampowered.com/api/storesearch?term=csgo&cc=us&l=en`

But it's only returning thumb image not an icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use api for example link like this: [http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key={YOURKEY}&format=json&steamid=76561198354325383&include_appinfo=1](http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=%7BYOURKEY%7D3&format=json&steamid=76561198354325383&include_appinfo=1)
Further informations can be found [here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetOwnedGames)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).